jdk21 virtual thread ArrayBlockingQueue.take() occupy many of CPU
I'm using netty websocket dispatch message to custom virtual thread executor.
Network layer as this:

receive message: Client -> netty websocket channel -> disruptor ringbuff -> ArrayBlockingQueue -> virtual thread logic handler loop
reponse message: virtual thread -> disruptor ringbuff -> netty websocket channel

The scenario is send echo benchmark from client <-> server
ArrayBlockingQueue work like this snippet in server:
 def routing(queue: ArrayBlockingQueue[InputMsg]): Unit = {
    var inputMsg: InputMsg = null
    while (true) {
      inputMsg = queue.take()
      // just simple response echo.
    }
  }

Besides, every websocket connection will new itself  ArrayBlockingQueue. There no many concurrrecy racing on take method.
I'm profiling there with JProfiler are a lot CPU time cost on queue.take(). But doesn't it should be unmounted when block? and why not show the time cost on virtual thread underlying switch rather then take method.



I think you can find something like "Call Tree" so that you will see the cpu time cost.

thanks @autext, I have question about cpu cost means in JProfiler. Does it contains wait time? The "Call Tree" shows it increase time even though there do nothing, such as Thread.join in GS2Main.main or Queue.poll

If you use platform threads instead of virtual, does ArrayBlockingQueue.poll hog CPU as it does with virtual?

@igor.zh, yeah. same result of QPS, cpu usage, flamegraph and call tree. I think it's because of few work thread here with echo loadtest mode.  I'm guess cpu cost in jprofiler contains block time.

Does it contains wait time? I don't know because I'm not very familiar with this feature. Do you have any other questions

Confusing of JProfiler metrics should be solved, I'm checking relative concept. Because no other tools support profiling virtual thread yet, in my view.

It seems to me that the JProfiler's snapshot and a snippet you brought in the question mismatch. The snippet indicates that you use ArrayBlockingQueue.take and the snapshot - that ArrayBlockingQueue.poll is involved. However, take does not involve poll directly or indirectly. Therefore, I'd suggest to post somewhere on GitHub an MRE. By other hand, poll, in contrary to take, is a non-waiting method and if it is called in loop (sign of bad design, maybe) it will certainly hog the CPU - that's what it is designed for.
